# How to number input in ascending order?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, io

I have input coming in form a file input.txt as two columns of strings such as:

```
string1 string2
string3 string4
etc.
```

I am trying to number the strings in ascending order starting form 0 but in such a way that repeating strings don't get assigned new values but keep the once already assigned to them.
I decided to use a set::find operation to do this, but I am having a hard time making it work. Here's what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

  std::ifstream myfile ("input.txt");
  std::string line;
  int num = 0;  // num is the total number of input strings

  if (myfile.is_open()) {      
      while(std::getline(myfile, line)) {
          ++num; 
      }
  }

  std::string str1, str1; // strings form input
  int str1Num, str2Num; // numbers assigned to strings

  int i = 0; // used to assign values to strings
  StringInt si;
  std::vector<StringInt> saveStringInts(num);
  std::set<std::string> alreadyCounted(num, 0); 
  std::set<std::string>::iterator sit;

  std::ifstream myfile2 ("input.txt");
  if (myfile2.is_open()) {      
      while(myfile2.good()) {
          // read in input, put it in vars below
          myfile2 >> str1 >> str2;

    // if strings are not already assigned numbers, assign them
    if ((*(sit = alreadyCounted.find(str1)).compare(str1) != 0) { // doesn't work
      str1Num = i++;
      alreadyCounted.insert(str1);
      saveStringInts.push_back(StringInt(str1Num));
    }
    else {
      str1Num = si->getNum(str1);
    }
    if ((*(sit = alreadyCounted.find(str2)).compare(str2) != 0) { 
      str2Num = i++;
      alreadyCounted.insert(str2);
      saveStringInts.push_back(StringInt(str2Num));
    }
    else {
      str2Num = si->getNum(str2);
    }

    // use str1 and str2 in the functions below before the next iteration


    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, I tried other approaches and now completely stuck. If you know how to fix my code or can suggest a better way to accomplish my task, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: **Always** test whether input was successful **after** you attempted to read your values, e.g., `while (myfile2 >> str1 >> str2) ...`

Comment: Yes, I tested it and the input was successful, I am getting the strings but can't number them in ascending order.

Comment: As is, your code will process the last line of input twice. It may be harmless in your case but in general it isn't.

Comment: How should I fix it? Sorry, I'm not very good at io.

Comment: Well, I already mentioned it in my first comment: `while (myfile2 >> str1 >> str2) { ... }`. Interestingly, you used a correct approach when reading the first file.

Comment: Oh, right, I remember reading about this somwehere and when I wrote the first line I did it right but after I came back to the code I changed things around and was in a hurry and wrote the incorrect version without thinking. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compare `std::set<int>::iterator` against the `end()` iterator of your set, rather than dereferencing the iterator and comparing its value against something! Actually, derferencing the `end()` iterator is undefined behavior:

```
if ((*(sit = alreadyCounted.find(str1)).compare(str1) != 0) // WRONG: don't do that!
```

should really be

```
if (alreadyCounted.find(str1) != alreadyCounted.end())
```

... and likewise for the other string. Personally, I would use a different technique, though: when `insert()`ing into a `std::set<T>`, you get back a pair of an iterator and an indicator whether the object was inserted. The latter together with the current set's size give the next value, e.g.:

```
bool result = alreadyCounted.insert(str1).second;
strNum1 = result? alreadyCounted.size() - 1: si->getNum(str1);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I have been trying to understand what the "std::pair<..." code you provided means, but I still can't quite grasp it. Could you explain it to me in a little more detail?

Comment: Should result simply be a bool as that is what `alreadyCounted.insert(str1).second` will return?

Comment: @LachlanEaston: Yes, I'll correct that. Somehow I started out thinking the count could be obtained from this set but it can't anyway.

Comment: @Napalidon: There was a small thinko (see above). The idea is that searching and inserting are roughly doing the same and they have some cost. Thus, using `insert()` immediately the search/insertion is done once. If the insertion doesn't do anything because the object is already there, the `second` member of the pair which is returned is set to `false` indicating it didn't insert anything. This way the set is searched just once.

Comment: @DietmarKuhl Dietmar, could you please explain to me why "alreadyCounted.find(str1) == alreadyCounted.end()" works in the if statement, is it because there is a hidden pointer that marches through starting at the beginning and going to end everytime to search for the matiching string?  why is it alreadyCounted.end()? Is there something I can read about this, I would like to understand why this syntax works.  Thank you.

Comment: @Napalidon: The definition of `set.find(x)` is to return an iterator to an element of `set` matching `x` or, if there is no such element, to return `set.end()`. There is nothing hidden about it: if you have a range with `n` elements, there are `n + 1` meaningful positions to talk about: pointing at each of the `n` elements and at the end. The `set.end()`, however, doesn't point to an element, i.e., it can't be dereferenced.